# How to join these columns efficiently (many rows) MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a following database schema:

```
Purchases          [PurchaseID, CustomerID, Date...]
PurchasesReturns   [PurchaseReturnID, PurchaseID, ...]
```

Purchases contain a huge amount of rows, while PurchasesReturns much less.

I would like to count, for every Customer that has ever made a Purchase Return (and only for them!), the amount of days from their very first Purchase until every Purchase Return. Example of output:

```
PurchaseID | CustomerID | DaysFromCustomersFirstPurchase
--------------------------------------------------------
       1001|           1|                            215
       1002|           1|                            216
       1003|           1|                            218
       1004|           2|                            184
       1005|           2|                            188
       1007|           4|                             24
       1008|           5|                            102
```

*Note - All of above Purchases were Returned (their IDs are in PurchasesReturns table)*

*Note - Purchases 1001,1002,1003 were made on different days, so the amount of days from the day that Customer 1 made his first Purchase are different.*

*Note - Customer of ID 3 never made a Purchase Return, so his Purchases are not there.*

I made something like that, but I am not sure that this is correct and it is not efficient for sure - it never ends (few hours of testing).

```
SELECT s1.PurchaseID, s1.CustomerID,
    FIRST_VALUE(s1.[Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY s1.CustomerID ORDER BY s1.Date) AS [Date]
FROM (SELECT s2.PurchaseID, s2.CustomerID, s2.[Date]
    FROM Purchases s2
    WHERE s2.CustomerID IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT s3.CustomerID
        FROM Purchases s3 
        WHERE s3.PurchaseID IN
            (SELECT s4.PurchaseID FROM PurchasesReturns s4))) s1
```

Additionaly - I only try to get the date of the very first Purchase, I would have to add the counting of days.

Thank you for your every advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the `purchases` table to get the first date and then `join`:

```
select pr.*,
       datediff(day, p.first_date, pr.date) as days_to_return
from purchasereturns pr join
     (select customerid, min(date) as first_date
      from purchases p
      group by customerid
     ) p
     on p.customerid = pr.customerid;
```

EDIT:

You want the difference on the purchase date not the return date.  For that:

```
select pr.*,
       datediff(day, p.first_date, p.date) as days_to_return
from purchasereturns pr join
     (select p.*,
             min(date) over (partition by customerid) as first_date
      from purchases p
     ) p
     on p.purchaseid = pr.purchaseid;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But to make everything clear - the day difference I want to count is difference between very first Purchase of the Customer and every Purchase that is returned (not the Return itself) - both dates that we are interested in come from Purchase table. Second thing - there is no CustomerID in PurchaseReturn, we have to get it from the Purchase. But, it was very helpful from you :)

Comment: @pablo11pablo11 . . . Thank you for the clarification.  In that case, a window function is more appropriate than aggregation.  It is really nice that you have the purchase id on the returns.  Not all databases have that information.

Comment: Two notes - I think it still counts days between first purchase of customer and the return? I would like to count between every Purchase (that has a Return in PurchaseReturn table) and the very first Purchase of the customer. Second thing - we would like to do it for every Purchase (that has Return), not for every PurchasesReturn.  Don't we have to select it from Purchase table (and filter it)?

Comment: @pablo11pablo11 .  . . I don't understand the second condition.  If a purchase can have more than one return, then perhaps aggregation or `select distinct` does what you want.

Comment: It's hard for me to explain. Nevertheless - thank you very much, you helped me a lot! :)